# Collapsed navbar push elements outside of parent container when shown (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

**Intro**

I'm using Bootstrap 5 (bundled with webpack 5), with his grid system and the collapse function to create the home page to this site, that has 2 sidebars that collapse into a topbar.

When we get to a mobile format the navs collapse and the columns containing them stack up leaving the 3rd col with the logo at the bottom without overflowing the parent.

Look at my 100% accurate ms paint graphics to understand better

**Issue**

When we show the collapsed navs, the columns containing them push the 3rd col with the logo out of the row and the container-fluid containing it.

**Question**

How can i make the navs expanding without pushing the logo? (to clarify the logo needs to stay below the navs

[ms paint 100% accurate graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m6aj.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 order-0 my-auto">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <a class="navbar-brand brand d-lg-none" href="#"
          ><b>ENV</b>Productions</a
        >
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive"
          aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
          <ul
            class="navbar-nav flex-column justify-content-between text-center text-lg-start"
          >
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#services">SEVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-10 order-lg-1 order-last my-auto text-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand brand d-none d-lg-block" href="#"
        ><b>ENV</b>Productions</a
      >
      <img
        src="assets/img/BG_ENV_MONO-800px.png"
        alt=""
        class="img-fluid"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-1 order-lg-2 my-auto">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end"
          id="navbarResponsive"
        >
          <ul
            class="navbar-nav flex-row flex-lg-column justify-content-around justify-content-lg-between"
          >
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
              <a
                href="https://www.instagram.com/env.productions/?hl=it"
                target="”_blank”"
                ><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i
              ></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
              <a
                href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIloBELeZR4x8jmrhIQXQCw/featured"
                target="”_blank”"
                ><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i
              ></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
              <a
                href="https://www.facebook.com/env.productions/"
                target="”_blank”"
                ><i class="fa fa-facebook-f fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i
              ></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item text-center">
              <a
                href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/env-productions/"
                target="”_blank”"
                ><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i
              ></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making the logo a background-image and merging the collapsible elements under the same parent with js.

There's probably a better solution though and maybe one that let you have the image at a block/inline level.